# google adsense conditional in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I use wordpress and recetly employed adsense. Following advice from google adsense I am trying to remove ads from unnecessary pages by using the following code in my header.

```
<?php if ( !is_page(array('29460', '32349')) || !is_404() || !is_preview() ) :?>

//GOOGLE ADSENSE CODE BLOCK

<?php endif;?>
```

The code does not seem to be working with all these sort of conditions together, any idea how I should restructure this code to make it work ?

Comment: Dear downvoter, would u be kind enough to share your logic behind your action please. In which way does this question deserve a downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to *hide* the Adsense block on page ID 29460, Page ID 32349, the 404 page and the preview, you should use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
<?php if ( !is_page(array('29460', '32349')) && !is_404() && !is_preview() ) :?>

//GOOGLE ADSENSE CODE BLOCK

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I thought the opertor `&&` meant, only if all the conditions matched.